# Как вызвать метод setOnClickFillInIntent для нескольких представлений?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как повесить слушатель setOnClickFillInIntent на несколько элементов в listView в виджете?
Если повесить один setOnClickFillInIntent только на один элемент, например кнопку, то всё нормально работает. А вот как быть, если кнопок две и при нажатии на каждую нужно производить разные действия?

Класс Provider:

```
override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

    for (i in appWidgetIds) { updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, i) }
}

private fun updateWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {
    val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_tasks_today)

    val adapter = Intent(context, TasksWidgetService::class.java)
    adapter.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)

    val data: Uri = Uri.parse(adapter.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
    adapter.data = data

    rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvTasksWidget, adapter)

    val listClickIntent = Intent(context, TasksWidgetProvider::class.java)
    listClickIntent.action = ConstAction.ACTION_ON_CLICK
    listClickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)

    val listClickPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, listClickIntent, 0)

    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.lvTasksWidget, listClickPIntent)

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv)
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.lvTasksWidget)
}
```

Сервис:

```
class TasksWidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent): RemoteViewsFactory {
        return TasksWidgetFactory(applicationContext, intent)
    }
}
```

Класс, в котором идёт работа listView:

```
class TasksWidgetFactory internal constructor(ctx: Context, intent: Intent) : RemoteViewsFactory {

    var data: ArrayList<Task> = arrayListOf<Task>()
    var context: Context = ctx


    override fun onCreate() { }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val rView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.item_list_tasks_widget)

        rView.setTextViewText(R.id.textItemTaskWidget, data[position].name)

        val clickIntent = Intent()
        clickIntent.putExtra(ITEM_POSITION, position)

        val clickDeleteIntent = Intent()
        clickDeleteIntent.putExtra("task", data[position])

        rView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.deleteItemTaskWidget, clickDeleteIntent)
        rView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.checkItemTaskWidget, clickIntent)

        return rView
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {
        data = getDataTasksForWidget()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым. В моём случае нужно сделать для каждой кнопки Intent и просто передать в каждом своё какое-то значение, по которому их можно будет потом отличить.

```
val clickDeleteIntent = Intent()
clickDeleteIntent.putExtra("clickDelete", true)
rView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.deleteItemTaskWidget, clickDeleteIntent)

val clickIntent = Intent()
clickIntent.putExtra(ITEM_POSITION, position)
clickIntent.putExtra("idTask", data[position].id)
clickIntent.putExtra("completedTask", data[position].completed)
rView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.checkItemTaskWidget, clickIntent)
```